# Custom metadata in order list column - woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm running Woocomerce store with ultimate member plugin. It is used to generate custom user meta (let's call it ID Buyer, stored in wp-usermeta meta-key Id_buyer). 99% of orders are made by registered users that filled Buyer ID field. Now - I was able to display this metadata in wp users column with following code:

```
function add_custom_column_name($columns) {
    $columns['ID_buyer'] = 'ID Buyer:';
    return $columns;
}
function show_custom_column_values($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'ID_buyer' == $column_name )
        return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'Id_buyer', true );
    return $value;
}

add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'add_custom_column_name');
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'show_custom_column_values', 10, 3);
```

I want to do the same for woocommerce order list. Making it sortable would be a plus. Is there any way to do it? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more or less the same thing:

```
function add_custom_order_column_name($columns) {
    $columns['ID_buyer'] = __('ID Buyer:', 'text-domain');
    return $columns;
}

function show_custom_order_column_values($column) {
    if ( 'ID_buyer' == $column ){
        global $the_order;
        if ($the_order->get_user_id()){
            echo get_user_meta( $the_order->get_user_id(), 'Id_buyer', true );
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_custom_order_column_name' );
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'show_custom_order_column_values' );
```